# Angular js ng-class false condition not working in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-class

I want to highlight `li` if that `radio` is selected. 
Inside `ng-repeat`, `ng-class` `true` condition is working, but `false` condition is not working, please check the code below

```
<div ng-init="friends = [
        {name:'John', age:25, gender:'boy'},
        {name:'Jessie', age:30, gender:'girl'},
        {name:'Johanna', age:28, gender:'girl'},
        {name:'Joy', age:15, gender:'girl'},
        {name:'Mary', age:28, gender:'girl'},
        {name:'Peter', age:95, gender:'boy'},
        {name:'Sebastian', age:50, gender:'boy'},
        {name:'Erika', age:27, gender:'girl'},
        {name:'Patrick', age:40, gender:'boy'},
        {name:'Samantha', age:60, gender:'girl'}
      ]">
        <ul class="example-animate-container">
          <li class="animate-repeat" ng-repeat="friend in friends" ng-class="{true:'hightlight',false:''}[radioBox==friend.name]">
             <input type="radio" name="friends" ng-model="radioBox" value="{{friend.name}}" />
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because the `ng-repeat` create a new child scope for each `li` element, thus every `li` element will has its own `radioBox` value in its own scope.

For more detail, read [Understanding-Scopes](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes).

You could avoid this problem by having a `.` in your `ng-model`, for example using `model.radioBox` like this:

```
<li class="animate-repeat" ng-repeat="friend in friends" ng-class="{true:'hightlight',false:''}[model.radioBox==friend.name]">
  <input type="radio" name="friends" ng-model="model.radioBox" value="{{friend.name}}" />
</li>
```

And in your controller, initialize the `model` beforehand:

```
$scope.model = {
  radioBox: undefined
};
```

**Example Plunker:** http://plnkr.co/edit/TcOrxhSzYtN2KCxF2M3g?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

> If the expression evaluates to an object, then for each key-value pair of the object with a truthy value the corresponding key is used as a class name.

```
ng-class="{'highlight':radioBox==friend.name}"
```